# How to use common values in many objects in C++?

Tags: c++, class, parameters, global

I need to instantiate many objects from a class, but each one of them needs to be aware of a certain value X that is common for every object of this class, like a global parameter. This is necessary for my constructors to work properly in my objects.

Is there a way to do that without passing the value as a constructor parameter? What I wanna do is use the same variable in all objects so I don't waste RAM.

*in my real situation it's not just an X value, is a 1024-dimmension int vector.

Comment: Pass that value into functions by reference, instead of by value so it's not making additional copies.

Comment: *1024-dimmension int vector* Seriously?

Comment: what is wrong with global variables? if you don't like them - static variable will work too

Comment: @deviantfan: probably a 1D vector of size 1024 entries, but I agree that isn't quite what the question says.

Comment: static member variable?

Comment: `class WhatNot { const int X = 1024; ... };` and use `X` in your constructors?  Or is X set at runtime, once, before any members of your class are created, and thereafter it stays unchanged?

Comment: Do you mean a vector with 1024 elements? I 1024 dimension vector is a bit different!

Comment: `This is necessary for my constructors to work properly in my objects` this concerns me, why do you need a big shared vector to construct your objects?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, it is defined at runtime only once, read from a config file. Then, it stays unchanged.

Comment: @NeilKirk Yes, sorry. It's because I'm working with file descriptors so usually I say n-dimension. But in fact it is 1 vector with 1024 elements.

The construction goes into this vector to produce a signature for each object, that's why I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want a vector of size 1024 as the shared variable across all your classes. You could do this:

```
class MyClass {

  static std::vector<int> s_my_vector;
}
```

This code would go into your header file. In your cpp file, you'd have to initialize the std::vector. However, I do not recommend this. Class static variables that require constructor calls (i.e. not primitives or POD types) have a lot of gotchas that I'm not planning to go into. I will offer a better solution however:

```
class MyClass {
  static std::vector<int> & GetMyVector()
  {
    static std::vector<int> my_vector;
    static bool initialized = MyVectorInit(my_vector);
    return my_vector;
  }

  static bool MyVectorInit(std::vector<int> & v)
  {
    v.resize(1024);
    ...
  }
 public:
  MyClass() {
    std::vector<int> & v = GetMyVector();
    ...
  }

  static void EarlyVectorInit()
  {
    GetMyVector();
  }
}
```

In this case, the static local variable ensures that there will only be one copy of my_vector, and you can get a reference to it by calling GetMyVector. Furthermore, the static bool initialized is guaranteed to only be created once, which means that MyVectorInit will only be called once. You can use this method in case you need to populate your vector in some non-trivial way that can't be done in the constructor. 
The way I've written it, your vector will be created automatically the first time you need to use it, which is fairly convenient. If you want to manually trigger creation for some reason, call EarlyVectorInit().

Comment: GetMyVector and related functions should be static.

Comment: I considered that. Is there any upside to making them static? Since they should be private anyhow (oops, forget to make ctor public), I'm having trouble thinking of how it could make a difference.

Comment: Why shouldn't they be static? They don't require any object to exist.

Comment: I suppose you are correct, in particular if the user wants to force the initialization of the vector before any objects are created (e.g. to control when the cost of initializing it is paid) then it has to be static. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @NirFriedman
Thank you very much for the answer. It was very helpful. What if I create a Class with these static members and create another class, which inherits that member? Can I instatiate the superclass once with that vector as a parameter on the constructor, and the other classes can access that vector?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a static member. "When a data member is declared as static, only one copy of the data is maintained for all objects of the class". e.g.

```
class myClass {
    public:
    static int x;
};
```